# how to stop rapid shaking on hover

Tags: html, css, web, iframe, css-animations

```css
iframe {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144),
    0 12px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377);
}
iframe:hover {
  filter: brightness(95%);
  transition:  0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation: iframes 0.8s linear both 1;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.212),
    0 16px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.493);
}
@keyframes iframes {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) ;
  }
}
```

```html
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d14023.546898520377!2d77.2038604!3d28.5130556!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xd87ca9af3beebff5!2sShrishti%20Flower!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1613667773659!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="60%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:2.7px blue solid; margin-bottom: 2rem; border-radius: 1rem; " allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```

<!-- iframe --!>

when I hover on this iframe it starts to shaking rapidly and the animation trigger more than once. I don't know why this happens . pls help me to solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the animation trigger more than once"?

Comment: when I hover  on this iframe my animation plays more than 1 time and also the brightness filter but I have already set the animation literate count to 1.

Comment: So you want your card to rotate 7 degrees then back 7 degrees only (i.e. not go -7 then back to 0)? And what's wrong with the brightness filter? How do you want it to happen?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In your example here in your question it does already behave as you're asking. One slow shake, then stop. Try it in your own question above - does it behave as you want? If it behaves correctly here then you've started the debugging process well, now you have an example that works, you need to look for what's different in your code that doesn't work. If when you test it on SO above you do see the repeated fast shaking then the problem must be browser specific as that's not what happens for me on firefox.

Comment: @Andrew thx your advice helped me now it is working properly . actually the problem was that on on hovering it rotates 7 deg and because of that it was going back to the unhovering state but the pointer is already there so it hovers again and this caused that rapid shaking.

Answer (score 0):

The shaking rapidly part I do not experience with your code snippet, the repeated animation is caused by having the animation on hover, this will reset the count everytime a user hovers the iframe.

By setting the animation on the iframe itself you can prevent this. You set start the animation on hover with `animation-play-state`.

```css
iframe {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144),
    0 12px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377);
  animation: iframes 0.8s linear both 1;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
iframe:hover {
  filter: brightness(95%);
  transition:  0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation-play-state: running;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.212),
    0 16px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.493);
}
@keyframes iframes {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) ;
  }
}
```

```html
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d14023.546898520377!2d77.2038604!3d28.5130556!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xd87ca9af3beebff5!2sShrishti%20Flower!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1613667773659!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="60%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:2.7px blue solid; margin-bottom: 2rem; border-radius: 1rem; " allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add "animation-iteration-count" to "infinite" for the shaking rapidly.

```css
iframe {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144),
    0 12px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377);
}
iframe:hover {
  filter: brightness(95%);
  transition:  0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation: iframes 0.8s linear both 1;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.212),
    0 16px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.493);
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
@keyframes iframes {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) ;
  }
}
```

```html
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d14023.546898520377!2d77.2038604!3d28.5130556!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xd87ca9af3beebff5!2sShrishti%20Flower!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1613667773659!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="60%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:2.7px blue solid; margin-bottom: 2rem; border-radius: 1rem; " allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I believe that's the opposite of what the OP asked for, they report the code they provided shakes repeatedly but they don't want it to.